# Share variable through ViewComposer and Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, service-provider

I have an admins array as a variable which is now declared in ViewComposer. However, now I want to use the same variable in middlewares too. Where is the best way to place a variable so I can share it through other files?

What I mean by [ViewComposers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers):

```
$admins = ['hello@example.com'];
```

Where should I define it so that I can access it both in Middleware and ViewComposer? Or maybe completely globally through the app?

(If it was a string, I'd use `.env` but it doesn't accept arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [configuration-values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)

```
$value = config('admins.list');// change admins and list is the key array returned
```

To set configuration values at runtime, pass an array to the config helper:

```
config(['admins.list' => [ 'admis list' ] ]);
```

`admins` would be inside config folder as `admins.php`

admins.php is something like following

```
return [
   'list' => [
       'admin1',
       'admin2'
   ],
   'other settings' => true
];
```